# Volunteer Labor Union in New York State

Tags: new-york-state, labor-law

In the state of New York, is it legal for a group of volunteers to form a [labor union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labor_unions_in_the_United_States)?

If not clearly legal, is there anything that prohibits a labor union of volunteers?

### Clarifing edit

I am specifically interested in a labor union, of volunteers supporting web sites.  The particular company I wonder about is headquartered in New York, it is [SE and we are all the volunteers in question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338316/217279)

Comment: Two tricky issues here: (1) What counts as a union for purposes of your question? (which is non-obvious and doesn't have one possible right answer, and (2) what do you really mean by "it is legal." It is possible, for example, for a union's existence not to violate any laws, but also not to qualify for special legal treatment restricted to certain kinds of private sector labor unions under the National Labor Relations Act. Is such a union "legal" or not, in the sense of your question.

Comment: Both answers have created a large tail of comments. @James, do you specifically mean the form of labor union indicated in the WIkipedia link, i.e. AFL-CIO members and similar local unions? And considering the Meta Stack Exchange question, do you mean a labor union for a private non-agricultural company?

Comment: @MSalters I am not entirely sure what I mean, as I don't have solid grasp of all the concepts.  I have edited the question to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

The formation of a labor union -- or virtually any other group -- is permitted by the First Amendment, which protects your right to associate with other people and your right "peaceably to assemble."

As a group of volunteers, there would likely be meaningful barriers to its recognition for the purposes of enforcement of collective-bargaining laws. In that case, whatever organization the volunteers are serving would likely not have a duty to negotiate with the union, though it may still choose to do so.

Comment: Why does the NLRA only cover certain groups if you can form a union for anything? https://www.nlrb.gov/rights-we-protect/rights/employee-rights

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong.

Comment: The law specifically leaves out certain groups such as " but shall not include any individual employed as an agricultural laborer, or in the domestic service of any family or person at his home".

Comment: How does the law exclude those groups yet comply with the First Amendment?

Comment: So many great questions! I can tell you're eager to get a basic grasp on constituttional and legal principles, so I'd recommend taking a beginner's-level class on constitutional law. It'll help you sort through all of this.

Comment: Maybe explaining your answer instead of just reading a book and assuming the words apply to everything when you have never been to court would help more than me taking a class.

Comment: It's prob easier for you to quote stuff you think applies from a textbook than to be in court irl though right?

Comment: I can tell you're very proud to have appeared in court that one time, or maybe even multiple times. If you were doing so to litigate questions at the intersection of labor law and the First Amendment, that appearance might be relevant to this discussion. Because it seems more likely that you were testifying about a DUI or something, I don't know how it's related. Anyway, it seems like you're upset at my criticism of your answer, so I'm going to let this conversation cool off till tomorrow. If you still want to engage then, let me know.

Comment: @Putvi The National Labor Relations Act isn't and isn't meant to be a comprehensive law covering all kinds of collective action through unions or something similar. It also doesn't cover public sector unions or non-employment related unions (e.g. tenant's unions) organized by, e.g., consumers, or self-employed people. It acknowledges and has some provisions for industry scale rather than employer level units (which works better in fields dominated by small firms) but is primarily for unions with single employer local units. Other law govern some non-NLRA unions (e.g. publc sector unions).

Comment: I'm telling you that from knowing a real judge and being in a real courtroom you can see how the law is actually practiced in ways you reading some articles online can not. That isn't meant to insult you, it's just that the intent of the law is clearly not to protect volunteers and outside of a theoretical discussion would never be applied that way irl.

Comment: @ohwilleke I agree that there are other laws. I'm saying the first amendment does not grant the right to any and all groups as he tried to falsely insinuate in the comments on my answer while voting my answer down, then saying that it would be hard or not recognized in his.

Comment: @ohwilleke "New York state law can choose which groups to give certain benefits, but it can do nothing to stop the formation of the union. – bdb484 " in the comments on my answer is what I was referring to.

Comment: @bdb484 how is it a union if it can't be recognized?

Comment: @Putvi Labor laws recognizing unions post-date unions by several decades.

Comment: @ohwilleke that is true, but now that NY has union laws, a union must fit into them to be recognized.

Comment: @Putvi The point is that an unrecognized union, isn't as a general rule, illegal.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can not form a union because a volunteer is not an employee. New York law gives employees the right to form unions.
https://www.perb.ny.gov/new-york-state-employment-relations-act/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101037/discussion-between-bdb484-and-putvi).

Comment: This answer's validity hinges on what counts as a union. Not every organization of people called a union and organized on those principles is a private sector union organized under the National Labor Relations Act (which incidentally even bans certain kinds of unions sponsored by employers).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101040/discussion-on-answer-by-putvi-volunteer-labor-union-in-new-york-state).